# Class Error: Fails to Declare Class

Tags: php, slim

I have a simple Php Class using composer autoload. But If Try to laod the Class I have Created It Return Error Fatal error: Class 'User' not found in C:\Users\Ilamini\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\E-learning\bootstrap\boot.php on line 11

my composer.json

```
 "autolaod" :{
            "psr-4":{
                "App\\" : "app"
            }
        }
```

the class

```
<?php

    namespace App\Models;

    /**
    * 
    */
    class User 
    {


    }
```

my bootstrap

```
require_once INC_ROOT.'/vendor/autoload.php';
$user =new \App\Models\User;
    var_dump($user);
    die();
```

bUt if require the User Class with Php Require Class it Work.

require_once INC_ROOT.'/app/Models/User.php';

```
$user =new \App\Models\User;
var_dump($user);
die();
```

I Autoload with Composer But Is not working;

Comment: I have no idea what INC_ROOT is... but I suspect you should probably be using `__DIR__` .. and some path traversals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I miss spelt autoload in the psr-4 composer code. So it Should be

```
 "autoload" :{
            "psr-4":{
                "App\\" : "app"
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include composers `autoload.php`file.

You don't need to `require_once INC_ROOT.'/app/Models/User.php'`

Comment: Yea I did add autoload.php